# SQL Server thinks i'm trying to convert varchar to int when using a hypen

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I run this SQL statement:

```
SELECT commentor, comment, cdate, ddate 
FROM delivery_comments
WHERE Jobno = '93388-01' and ddate = '2016-03-11'
ORDER BY cdate
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '93388-01' to data type int.

I'm not trying to convert it to an int. I want it to stay `varchar`. How do I do this?

Comment: What data type is jobNo in delivery_comments?  show the table structure for delivery_comments.  My guess is JobNo is integer so the system is trying to do an implicit cast which it is failing.

Comment: Well darn. It is "int". That really messes me up.

Comment: :P I can't fix that I'm guessing JobNo elsewhere isn't int :P

Comment: So to fix... why do you think job number could be '93388-01'? when the field is an int.... what's the source of the 93388-01?

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with @xQbert, why are you comparing type of varchar with int along with '-' (hyphen) when its sure that int never has such value...

you can do the comparison like as follows :

```
Cast(Jobno As Varchar(20)) = '93388-01'
```

still you never get the result as '-' (hyphen) never exists in your data.